# Expectation of N(d2)?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, probability

I am trying to find out the Pricing Equation for certain type of Options under Risk-Neutral pricing. This is the equation I am getting, but I am not sure if this can be solved or not. Any help is appreciated.

$$V = E[I\{S(T_0) \geq B\}N(d_2)]$$

$t_0 < T_0 < T_1$     This is a time line

$$I\{S(T_0) \geq B\} =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } S(T_0) \geq B \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

where $S(t_0), S(T_0)$ is the stock price at different times.

$N(d_2)$ is the Black Scholes $N(d_2)$ but Stock Price used in $N(d_2)$ is $S(T_0)$, and time period is $T_1-T_0$. So $N(d_2)$ in itself is a Random Variable in this case.

I am trying to find the Expectation at **time $= t_0$**

$ d_2 = [ln(S(T_0)/K)+(r-0.5vol^2)(T_1-T_0)] / (vol* sqrt (T_1-T_0)) $

$ S(T_0) = S(t_0) exp((r-0.5vol^2)(T_0-t_0) + vol * sqrt(T_0-t_0)Z)    $

Z~N(0,1)

Comment: You want the expectation of a [digittal option](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/digitaloption.asp)?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to compute the above expectation at time=t0. But the N(d2) that I have is based on a future time T0. So that is the Probability of S(T1)>K at time T1 standing at time T0 So my question is there anyway to compute this expectation?

Comment: If it's jsut about the expectation, and you don't care about the value (i.e. you can ignore discounting), then why not just price the binary option at $T_0$ with no discounting?

Comment: Aah i understand. You have a binary option, but it's multiplied by $N(d_2)$ on the future date? How are the other parameters of $d_2$ chosen on that date? Are they fixed in the terms?

Comment: My main goal is not to price a Binary Option. I am trying to Price a KI Option at time t0, where KI happens at time T0 and final payoff happens at time T1 based on KI event. I was able to reduce my original Pricing formula based on Iterated Expectations and the above expectation is just a part of my reduced formula after using iterated expectation. My only concern is , is there anyway to compute this expectation? Can I compute the expectation of N(d2) or N(d1) if they are a random variable as well?

Comment: The other parameters of d2  are :- S(T0) this is future stock price, time period = T1-T0, Strike is K chosen at time t0, let's say r and vol are constant based on time t0

Comment: I see. So, normally the easiest way to find answers to these is to  write it as an integral, and then check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions) page to see if you can match it to anything! As a side note -how are you choosing the single vol? The strike of the option? or the KI level? You could also take another shortcut - depending on $T0$ and $T1$ - you could price a KI option as a static portfolio at $T1$, with $B^\prime = B \frac{F(T_1)}{F(T_0)}$.

Comment: I just had a look at it - i think it's unlikely you'll find a form with an analytic answer. What i would do is just price it over a range of scenarios and then integrate with the probability density - but if you're going down that route, you might as well just do it for the whole thing...

Comment: If an analytic form is not feasible I can use Monte Carlo Simulation anyways. I was looking for a closed form solution. Probably there are some closed form solutions already for such things?

Comment: You can still do some sort of numerical integration before you go for mc though.

Comment: In the special case where $T_1-T_0=T_0$, you may be able to have an analytical valuation formula.

Comment: @Gordon - Do you mean $T_1 - T_0 = T_0 - t_0$? Can you elaborate plz?

Comment: @DebdiptaMajumdar: Yes. $T_1-T_0=T_0-t_0$.

Comment: Ok. But how do I reach to an analytical solution in that case? $S(T_0)$ is still unknown to me at $t_0$. Can you show some steps if possible? Thanks

Comment: @DebdiptaMajumdar: It still has some difficulties. I may have overlooked a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially interested in pricing a second order bond-binary option. In its most general form, this contract has a time $T_2$ payoff of

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_{\xi_1, \xi_2}^{s_1, s_2} \left( S_{T_1}, S_{T_2}, T_2 \right)  = \mathrm{1} \left\{ s_1 S_{T_1} > s_1 \xi_1 \right\} \mathrm{1} \left\{ s_2 S_{T_2} > s_2 \xi_2 \right\}.
\end{equation}

In your case, we have $\xi_1 = B$, $s_1 = +1$, $\xi_2 = K$ and $s_2 = +1$. The time $T_1$ value of this option is equal to

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_{\xi_1, \xi_2}^{s_1, s_2} \left( S_{T_1}, T_1 \right)  = \mathrm{1} \left\{ s_1 S_{T_1} > s_1 \xi_1 \right\} e^{-r \left( T_2 - T_1 \right)} \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \mathrm{1} \left\{ s_2 S_{T_2} > s_2 \xi_2 \right\} \right| S_{T_1} \right].
\end{equation}

Apart from the additional discounting, this is the same expression as in your question.

This contract is a special case of the generalize multi-period and multi-asset $\mathbb{M}$-binary options analyzed by Skipper and Buchen (2003). Its time $0 \leq t < T_1$ value is given by

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_{\xi_1, \xi_2}^{s_1, s_2} \left( S_t, t \right) = e^{-r \tau_2} \mathcal{N}_2 \left( \alpha_{0, 1}, \alpha_{0, 2}; \rho \right),
\end{equation}

where $\tau_i = T_i - t$,

\begin{equation}
\alpha_{0, i} = \frac{s_i}{\sigma \sqrt{\tau_i}} \left( \ln \left( \frac{S}{\xi_i} \right) + \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \tau_i \right)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\rho = s_1 s_2 \sqrt{\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}}.
\end{equation}

Here, $\mathcal{N}_2$ is the bivariate standard normal distribution function with the given correlation. See the original paper for a derivation of this result. You find a similar result in Chapter 2 of the Ph.D. thesis Veiga (2010). See also [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31199) related question and the corresponding answers.

**References**

Skipper, Max and Peter W. Buchen (2003) "The Quintessiential Option Pricing Formula", Working Paper, School of Mathematics and Statistics, University of Sydney, [available online](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/pubs/publist/preprints/2003/skipper-22.pdf)

Veiga, Carlos Manuel "Closed Formulas and Rating Schemes for Derivatives", Ph.D. Thesis, Frankfurt School of Finance & Management, [available online](http://d-nb.info/1011760029/34)